# Calculate time difference between two events while disregarding unmatched events in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which look like this

```
id  code    time
abc a100    26-09-2019 14:55
abc a109    25-09-2019 22:09
abc a100    26-09-2019 20:10
abc a106    26-09-2019 20:15
abc a100    26-09-2019 22:59
abc a190    26-09-2019 23:05
abc a106    26-09-2019 23:08
abc a100    26-09-2019 23:49
def a106    26-09-2019 23:55
def a100    27-09-2019 15:42
def a106    27-09-2019 15:47
def a100    27-09-2019 16:03
def a190    27-09-2019 16:07
def a106    27-09-2019 16:09
```

[data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBuFq.png)

For each id, i need to find the time difference between two code(column_name) which may or may not be in sequence. For example in id "abc" i need to find the difference between "a100" and "a106":
1.it can contain some different codes in between them which should be discarded and the difference to be calculated.
2.it can contain "a100" multiple times before "a106" we need to take the most recent "a100" for "a106".
3.we need it for the ids.

and i have different pairs like ("a100","a106"), ("a109","a110") etc. so i can have mean for all the pairs for each id and overall mean for every pair of code.

Required result for (a106-a100) code :
    [required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfc6z.png)
I am using python for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a [working minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use the syntax highlighting. Your post is quite hard to read, if you don't use it. What exactly is your question?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: @jhoepken i have added the required result. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you need but this may help:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


data = """
id,code,time
abc,a100,26-09-2019 14:55
abc,a109,25-09-2019 22:09
abc,a100,26-09-2019 20:10
abc,a106,26-09-2019 20:15
abc,a100,26-09-2019 22:59
abc,a190,26-09-2019 23:05
abc,a106,26-09-2019 23:08
abc,a100,26-09-2019 23:49
def,a106,26-09-2019 23:55
def,a100,27-09-2019 15:42
def,a106,27-09-2019 15:47
def,a100,27-09-2019 16:03
def,a190,27-09-2019 16:07
def,a106,27-09-2019 16:09
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',', parse_dates=['time'])
```

1: Only keep last time for each code (your point 2)

```
most_recent_per_code = df.sort_values('time').groupby(['id', 'code'], as_index=False).last()
```

2: Only keep first and last code per id (your point 1)

```
first_last_code = most_recent_per_code.groupby('id').nth([0,-1])
```

3: Show difference of time between first and last code

```
first_last_code.groupby('id').time.diff()
```

I do not get the last part of the question.

**Update**

Not the nicest solution but this may work to generate a similar output what you request:

```
# reading df as above
df = df.sort_values('time')

# codes we want to get diffs for (from code1 to code2)
code1 = 'a100'
code2 = 'a106'

# only keep codes we are interested in
df2 = df[df.code.isin([code1, code2])]

# remove subsequent codes and keep only newest
# this is done by comparing the code series with a -1 shifted series of the code (df2.code == df2.code.shift(-1))
# only keep rows where the code of the following row is different. This is achieved with the bitwise not (~)
df2 = df2[~(df2.code == df2.code.shift(-1))]

# helper function to get diffs for code and make sure to start with code1
# loop over the rows for each group
# if row starts with code1 calculate time diff to following row and store information in list
# continue to following row otherwise
def get_time_diffs(gr, code1):
    data = []
    for i in range(len(gr)-1):
        if gr.iloc[i].code != code1:
            continue
        time_diff = gr.iloc[i+1].time - gr.iloc[i].time
        data.append({
            'code1': gr.iloc[i].code,
            'code1_time': gr.iloc[i].time,
            'code2': gr.iloc[i+1].code,
            'code2_time': gr.iloc[i+1].time,
            'time_diff': time_diff})
    return pd.DataFrame(data)

# group by id and use helper function to get diff
df2.groupby('id').apply(lambda gr: get_time_diffs(gr, code1))
```

Comment: Hi @mjspier . I have added sample result for the last part. please have a look

Comment: Can you please explain working of: 1. Bitwise NOT operator(~) in line # remove subsequent codes and keep only newest
df2 = df2[~(df2.code == df2.code.shift(-1))]    and 2. gr in  get_time_diffs function

Comment: I added some information in the comments in the code. If still not clear let me know

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate your id and code column in separate column and use as id
Then you can use groupby to find min and max time:

```
df_time_max_min = df_conf.groupby('id-code')['timestamp'].agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index()
```

and then just find the difference:

```
df_time_max_min['diff_days'] = df_time_max_min['max'] - df_time_max_min['min']
df_time_max_min['diff_days']= (df_time_max_min['diff_days']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')).round(2)
```

Comment: Hi @s_khan92 . I have added sample result. please have a look